# Correct way to handle resources in Spring Jetty and Camel

Tags: java, spring, jetty, apache-camel, jedis

I've a webapp (Jetty, Spring and Camel). Now I want to connect to a Redis (using Jedis) in my a Camel route. My question where (and when) should I create the Jedis pool and how can I get access to this pool in my Camel routes ? I was thinking about creating the pool in my Camel context XML. But I'm not sure how can I get access to this pool in my route (Java DSL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can now (as of 2.11) use [camel-redis](http://camel.apache.org/redis) to send and receive messages from Redis

Comment: Yeah I know. But there are some other elements for which is no Camel component available yet. I was interesting in knowing the generic approach if I wanted to add my own component.

Comment: you can always just call a bean from a Camel route to wrap access to any resource (initialized in camel.xml, etc)...or write your own component as described here: http://camel.apache.org/creating-a-new-camel-component.html